# ng-repeat & javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is my object:

```
     $scope.tickets = [{
         title: "Bug 1",
         number: 1,
         desc: 'Description #1',
         assigned: [{
             name: "Someone",
             group: "Development"
         }]
     },
     {
         title: "Bug 2",
         number: 2,
         desc: 'Description #1',
         assigned: [{
             name: "someone2",
             group: "Development"
         }]
     },
     {
         title: 'Random unknown issue',
         number: 3,
         desc: 'Description #3',
         assigned: [{
             name: "Someone3",
             group: "Support"
         }]
     }];
```

1. I am doing a table to display all the content and inside im doing an hg-repeat but i do not know how to access the name and group info under the assigned

   ```
   <p class="lead">Development:</p>
   <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <!-- <th>index</th> -->
           <th>#</th>
           <th>Title</th>
           <th>Description</th> 
           <th>Group/Assigned</th>
           <th>Advanced</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
           <td>{{ticket.number}}</td>
           <td>{{ticket.title}}</td>
           <td>{{ticket.desc}}</td>
           <td>{{ticket.assigned.group}} / {{ticket.assigned.name}}</td>
           <td>
             <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendToSupport(ticket)">Send to Support</button>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table> 
   </div>
   ```
2. I have tried filtering the ng-repeat by

   ```
    | filter: {group: 'Support'}
   ```

and does not work

1. aslo as you can see im sending the object into an ng-click

   ```
   <tr ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
    <td>{{ticket.number}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.title}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.desc}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.assigned.group}} / {{ticket.assigned.name}}</td>
    <td>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendToSupport(ticket)">Send to Support</button>
    </td>
   ```

what i am doing is this

```
      $scope.sendToDev = function(ticket){
        this.ticket.assigned.group = "Support"
     }
```

seems ok?

Comment: Where is the ng-app and ng-controller attrs? also, please upload the angular declarations in your js file.

Comment: ng-app is inside my html tag 
         <html ng-app="app">

my controller is in a div

          <!--ticketsController-->
           <div class="container" ng-controller="ticketsCtrl">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined assigned as an array of object

```
assigned: [{
             name: "Someone3",
             group: "Support"
         }]
```

Define it as a object (without the []) or access it as an array.

```
assigned: {
             name: "Someone3",
             group: "Support"
         }
```

If you really need it to be an array, use a nested ng-repeat like this :

```
<td><div ng-repeat="assigned in ticket.assigned">{{assigned.group}} / {{assigned.name}}</div></td>
```

Comment: how would you filter by the group?

Comment: ng-repeat="assigned in ticket.assigned | filter: {group: 'Support'}"

Comment: I did it yesterday before answering you on a plunker that I did discard and it was working. Try again. If you are not able to do it, I will give you a plunker tonight.